# How to make step in 10 points without save value outside?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Actually what I need is I have a progress bar logic that tracking every second count of files, but case here that I don't need to update every time when I get trigger, like 1%, 3%, 7% ... I would like to define kind of step_progress variable (for example 10) and get this progress bar update steps like 10%, 20%, 30%...

So, for this case I wrote such logic

```
...
->set_progress_bar_callback([&](int count, int copied_file) {
        const int PROGRESS_UPDATE_STEP = 10;
        const int MAX_PERCENTAGE = 100;
        float progress_step = (float)MAX_PERCENTAGE / (float)count;
        float progress_result = progress_step * copied_file;

        if ((int)progress_result % PROGRESS_UPDATE_STEP == 0)
        {
            if (progress_callback != nullptr)
            {
                printf("HERE!!! execute_copy_process Progress count %f\n", progress_result);
                progress_callback(progress_result);
            }
        }
}
```

and I need to mention that **I don't want to define outside variable**(like class member), I would like that all this values should be inside lambda.

So, as you can see `count` - is a full amount (for example 124), and `copied_file` - it is a progress(for example 34)

Thus I calculate `progress_result` and try to get module(%) in order to understand if it is step of 10, but issue here that not every time `progress_result` value came to round number and eventually I get my progress like 10%, 40%, 60%...

Is there is some kind of trick to do it without to save outside values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stay in integer arithmetic.

```
[&](int current, int total) {
    const int PROGRESS_UPDATE_STEP = 10;
    const int MAX_PERCENTAGE = 100;
    int step = std::max(total * PROGRESS_UPDATE_STEP / MAX_PERCENTAGE, 1);

    if ((current % step) == 0)
    {
        if (progress_callback != nullptr)
        {
            float progress_result = static_cast<float>(current) / total;
            printf("HERE!!! execute_copy_process Progress count %f\n", progress_result);
            progress_callback(progress_result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me `PROGRESS_UPDATE_STEP / MAX_PERCENTAGE == 0` always because of it is integers thus `count % progress_step` here I get an error `devision by ziro` , but in some cases I really came to `printf` line, but values always like `0,4`, `0,7`

Comment: That would only be the case if `copied_file` is less than 10. See edit for fix